# calling the function of derived class c++ from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

How i can call the function of derived class, **without** typecasting?

base type:

```
class Fruit{
public: 
    virtual void show() {cout « "its a fruct" « endl;}
};
```

child:

```
class Banana : public Fruit{
public: 
    void show() { cout « "it's yellow banana" « endl; }
};
```

array of derived pointers

```
class Basket
{
  Fruit *fructs_; 
  //... 
public:
  void show();
  //...
};

void Basket:: show(){
  for(int i=0; i< index_; i++)
  (fructs_+i)->show(); // need call Banana::show here
}
```

Comment: 'Banana' is not a base of 'Fruct'
(fructs_+i)->Banana::show(); It will work in the reverse situation(call Fruct method from banana pointer)

Comment: As it is virtual function, won't it call the derived class automatically?

Comment: @NeilKirk look at type of fructs_. Its base-type pointer.

Comment: That isn't an array of derived pointers. Its a pointer to one or more *objects*. And you're all-but-guaranteed to encountered a [slicing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) until you understand that.

Comment: If a fruit pointer, points to a bananna object, calling show on it, will call bananna's function.

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand it. The question is not in the method of naming.

Comment: @StasShakirov Who said anything about *naming* ? The provided code, the dereference through `fructs_+i`, is performing typed-pointer arithmetic on `fructs_` which is of type `Fruits`. If your intent is to have an array of pointers to polymorphic derivations accessed through a common base, that isn't going to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C-style arrays cannot be used polymorphically because of complications with the sizes of the base and derived classes. You should use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `Fruit` [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead:

```c++
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fruit>> fruits;
```

Comment: @NeilKirk Oh yeah. :)

Comment: it doesn't have to be "smart" pointers but I am agreed that using smart pointers is better than raw pointers